# Convert string "[1,2,3]" to array [1,2,3] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string which is structured as a list of arrays.

`"['Test', 1, 'Test 2'],['Test 3', 2, 'Test 4]"`

how to do I convert the string to be an array

`['Test', 1, 'Test 2'],['Test 3, 2, 'Test 4']`

I've tried eval and it only interprets the first array `['Test', 1, 'Test 2']`

Comment: Fix the input so it's in proper JSON format instead, and then `JSON.parse` it

Comment: Do you want it to be one array with all 6 values, or an array containing two more arrays with three values each?

Comment: An array of arrays.  let arr = [ ['test',1,2], ['test 2', 3, 4] ]

Comment: What is the expected output since it is two arrays with a comma?

Comment: I've got a string "[test], [test], [test]" what I need is for it to be ['test'], ['test']. To dumb it down I just need the quotes "" removing off either end of the string

Comment: Why is it not a valid nested array to start? The best fix is to fix whatever is outputting this bad format. Other fix is just adding [ and ] in the eval, but eval is a bad choice.

Comment: Please share your attempts by editing the question. Also, are there any more cases that are more difficult?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use eval.

The same thing can be done like this:

```
let str = "['Test', 1, 'Test 2'],['Test 3', 2, 'Test 4']";
let arr = JSON.parse(`[${str}]`.replaceAll("'", '"'));
```

Comment: Thanks this works, what's the issue with using eval?

Comment: eval allows attackers to add malicious code to the string. Imagine `str = "]; alert('gotcha'); ["`

Answer (score 0):

your string is not an array. but you may need something like this.

```
var str = "['Test', 1, 'Test 2'],['Test 3', 2, 'Test 4']";
var arr; 
eval('arr = [' + str + ']')
```

Comment: Do not use eval